# Does upgrading from 32bit to 64bit windows delete all of my discs?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, 64-bit

Does upgrading from 32bit to 64bit windows delete all of my discs or just the one where windows is instaled? I have 3 discs (C:, D: and E:) and windows is instaled on my C: drive. When I upgrade to 64bit will it delete just the files from my C: drive or all of my drives?

C:, D: and E: discs are all segments of 1 hdd, not multiple hdds.

Comment: Whether or not you can, in theory, preserve you files, you should always take a complete backup before upgrading the OS.

Answer (score 5):

As long as you don't intentionally format the d: and e: drives during the upgrade they will be left untouched by installation process.Just make sure Windows is installed on the c: drive/partition. The custom option installs a new copy of Windows on the partition you choose. This erases your files, programs, and settings so make sure you backup first important files and settings so that you can restore them after the upgrade. You will also need to reinstall all your programs after the installation.

Answer (score 0):

The terms 32-bit and 64-bit refer to the way a computer's processor (also called a CPU), handles information. The 64-bit version of Windows handles large amounts of random access memory (RAM) more effectively than a 32-bit system. If you are currently running a 32-bit version of Windows, you can only perform an upgrade to another 32-bit version of Windows. Similarly, if you are running a 64-bit version of Windows, you can only perform an upgrade to another 64-bit version of Windows.

If you want to move from a 32-bit version of Windows to a 64-bit version of Windows, you'll need to back up your files and then perform a Custom installation of the 64-bit version of Windows. For more information, see [Installing and reinstalling](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/installing-reinstalling-windows#1TC=windows-7) Windows.

Answer from [**here**](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/efcd4783-e948-4f85-9659-7a6e9139a931/upgrading-from-windows-7-32bit-to-64bit).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upgrade 32-bit over 64-bit or vice versa, so you would need to custom install i.e. a fresh install of windows of 64-bit. Also before installing keep a check of your drives so you can identify them with their sizes when installing windows to avoid unintentional deletion of your personal drives. You can only delete files on your intention as windows does not intend to delete any file in any drive you install windows. Also if you're trying to install windows on a previously installed windows all the files will be transferred to "windows.old" folder so you can access it any time(to delete that folder you can clean disk that drive).